# Find Total Occurrence of a Variable Based on Another Variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to provide a SQL query to find which `XNumber`s had the most `YNumber`s.  Here is my data:

```
-- Create Tables
    -- Create X Table
        CREATE TABLE X (
            XID int identity,
            XNumber varchar(100) not null,
            XDescription varchar(100) not null,
            XCode varchar(100) not null,
            VIT varchar(100) not null,
            XLocation varchar(100) not null,
            CONSTRAINT PK_X PRIMARY KEY (XID),
            CONSTRAINT U1_X UNIQUE (XNumber),
            CONSTRAINT U2_X UNIQUE (XCode)
        )
        
    -- Create Y Table
        CREATE TABLE Y (
            YID int identity,
            YNumber varchar(100) not null,
            YDescription varchar(100) not null,
            YDate datetime not null default GetDate(),
            CONSTRAINT PK_Y PRIMARY KEY(YID),
            CONSTRAINT U1_Y UNIQUE(YNumber)
        )
        
    -- Create XY Table
        CREATE TABLE XY (
            XYID int identity,
            XID int not null,
            YID int not null,
            CONSTRAINT PK_XY PRIMARY KEY(XYID),
            CONSTRAINT FK1_XY FOREIGN KEY(XID) REFERENCES X(XID),
            CONSTRAINT FK2_XY FOREIGN KEY(YID) REFERENCES Y(YID)
        )


-- Insert Values in X
        insert into X (XNumber, XDescription, XCode, VIT, XLocation) values ('ASDLKVNAEQRIUNBVLAXKD', 'THDSDF', 'Violet', 2, 'FROP');
        insert into X (XNumber, XDescription, XCode, VIT, XLocation) values ('GBOGJMBNNUTHDFHJG', 'TFGSDFG',    'Pink', 20, 'DOOO');
        insert into X (XNumber, XDescription, XCode, VIT, XLocation) values ('GKHL', 'SDFGSDF', 'Yellow', 21, 'DSUIO');
        insert into X (XNumber, XDescription, XCode, VIT, XLocation) values ('DELKMDTKJGBT', 'HNYDGH', 'Green', 20, 'KABBA');
        insert into X (XNumber, XDescription, XCode, VIT, XLocation) values ('WRTOUBHNPSDFIVKM', 'OYIU', 'Aquamarine', 19, 'SANFRIO');
        insert into X (XNumber, XDescription, XCode, VIT, XLocation) values ('FGBKMOSEKFVKF', 'DCGTH', 'Red', 8, 'BOB');
        insert into X (XNumber, XDescription, XCode, VIT, XLocation) values ('GBIMGIK', 'FTGHJM', 'Mauv', 10, 'CHURCH');
        insert into X (XNumber, XDescription, XCode, VIT, XLocation) values ('JLJLH', 'FCTGHKII', 'Goldenrod', 5, 'ZAN');
        insert into X (XNumber, XDescription, XCode, VIT, XLocation) values ('YITORKRKG', 'ITRTGJJ', 'Maroon', 7, 'ZERR');
        insert into X (XNumber, XDescription, XCode, VIT, XLocation) values ('QWYTWEGD', 'PRTHJHJUKKM', 'Khaki', 9, 'ZAB');

    -- Insert Values in Y

        insert into Y (YNumber, YDescription, YDate) values ('8e3ac22d07ee88efa9e91fc0830cdee0f1263d82', 'POSTY', '12/22/2019');
        insert into Y (YNumber, YDescription, YDate) values ('735c653fec21726598b47b8c59f7b4a4a8ee3618', 'PUTH 3500', '1/14/2021');
        insert into Y (YNumber, YDescription, YDate) values ('ef3b991a287db1c3bfd9c568972bc35e5c7c6218', 'BTS', '4/4/2021');
        insert into Y (YNumber, YDescription, YDate) values ('a45cec89ba00b77439802b342ce16be4c8ddbee4', 'JLO', '12/3/2019');
        insert into Y (YNumber, YDescription, YDate) values ('747a92666a65947e9f03fd7cf7ad55fdd803a2ab', 'JT', '5/1/2020');
        insert into Y (YNumber, YDescription, YDate) values ('19a5e1d0c75abea249e50997dd1252285c36404c', 'M5', '1/13/2022');
        insert into Y (YNumber, YDescription, YDate) values ('1fe285c2249937f9c5c7608f46be736840ef6007', 'Laroi', '12/12/2021');
        insert into Y (YNumber, YDescription, YDate) values ('e6d3614571648dceae07a4813824904f70bc4bef', 'Biebs', '5/1/2022');
        insert into Y (YNumber, YDescription, YDate) values ('2a7401fd3f68e09f45564ff29fc4b16c1f7e88ba', 'The Weeknd', '2/21/2022');
        insert into Y (YNumber, YDescription, YDate) values ('20a451d4be1894e8f585af47807df6cbe55edfe4', 'Taylor', '2/1/2022');

    -- Insert Values in XY

        insert into XY (XID, YID) values (2, 6);
        insert into XY (XID, YID) values (6, 3);
        insert into XY (XID, YID) values (3, 3);
        insert into XY (XID, YID) values (9, 8);
        insert into XY (XID, YID) values (5, 7);
        insert into XY (XID, YID) values (4, 1);
        insert into XY (XID, YID) values (3, 7);
        insert into XY (XID, YID) values (3, 2);
        insert into XY (XID, YID) values (5, 9);
        insert into XY (XID, YID) values (6, 5);
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
        SELECT 
            X.XNumber,
            COUNT(XNumber) AS XFreq,
            Y.YNumber
            --COUNT(YNumber) AS YFreq
        FROM XY
        JOIN X ON X.XID = XY.XID
        JOIN Y ON Y.YID = XY.YID
        GROUP BY XNumber, YNumber
```

The result comes back as a row of just `1`s, which isn't correct.

Desired output would be a SELECT statement that answers the question: Which `XNumber`s had the most `YNumber`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each "Xnumber", you want to count the "YNumber", so just count "YNumber" and group by "Xnumber".

Since you only need the most "YNumber"s, use `RANK()` function.

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=cbb1ca693738ec33ffbfba1d4201ee6d)

```
        WITH tmp AS (
        SELECT 
            X.XNumber,
            COUNT(Y.YNumber) AS YFreq,
            RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(Y.YNumber) DESC) AS rnk
        FROM XY
        JOIN X ON X.XID = XY.XID
        JOIN Y ON Y.YID = XY.YID
        GROUP BY X.XNumber
        )
        
        SELECT tmp.*
        FROM tmp
        WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Oh, I see. So it looks like my main issue was also SELECTing Y.YNumber when I was also SELECTing COUNT(Y.YNumber), right? @EmbraceNothingButFuture

Comment: Basically, your two issues would be, 1)selecting Y.YNumber, 2) group by Y.YNumber.

Comment: Okay great! Thanks so much. Can you elaborate on the ‘’’tmp.*’’’? I’m not totally understanding what it’s saying. @EmbraceNothingButFuture

Comment: As you can see from the first line, the  "WITH tmp AS" thing is known as "common table expressions", it is a table alias the same thing when you do a subquery you would add a table alias at the end of the subquery. Inside the brackets of it would be the subquery or results table. Answering your question, "tmp.*" would be "tmp.XNumber, tmp.YFreq, tmp.rnk". The ```*``` means everything in the table.

Answer (score 2):

You're grouping by *both* columns. All rows are unique, which means each group will have a single row only. If you want to count the Ys, group by X only :

```
SELECT 
    X.XNumber,
    COUNT(*) AS XFreq
FROM XY
JOIN X ON X.XID = XY.XID
GROUP BY XNumber
ORDER BY Count(*) desc
-------------------------
XNumber             XFreq
GKHL                3
WRTOUBHNPSDFIVKM    2
FGBKMOSEKFVKF       2
GBOGJMBNNUTHDFHJG   1
YITORKRKG           1
DELKMDTKJGBT        1
```

You don't need to JOIN with Y because you aren't using any information from that table.

You can add a ranking with `ROW_NUMBER()` as well, to rank rows by count :

```
SELECT 
    X.XNumber,
    COUNT(*) AS XFreq,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc) as RN
FROM XY
JOIN X ON X.XID = XY.XID
GROUP BY XNumber
ORDER BY Count(*) desc
-------------------------
XNumber             XFreq   RN
GKHL                3       1
WRTOUBHNPSDFIVKM    2       2
FGBKMOSEKFVKF       2       3
GBOGJMBNNUTHDFHJG   1       4
YITORKRKG           1       5
DELKMDTKJGBT        1       6
```

You can't use ranking functions in a WHERE clause though. To filter by the row number column (RN) you need to wrap the original query as a CTE or subquery

```
;with ranks as (
    SELECT 
        X.XNumber,
        COUNT(*) AS XFreq,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc) as RN
    FROM XY
    JOIN X ON X.XID = XY.XID
    GROUP BY XNumber
)
SELECT * 
FROM ranks 
WHERE RN=1
-------------------
XNumber XFreq   RN
GKHL    3       1
```

or the equivalent

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        X.XNumber,
        COUNT(*) AS XFreq,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc) as RN
    FROM XY
    JOIN X ON X.XID = XY.XID
    GROUP BY XNumber
) ranks
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: Is this just counting the frequency of X.XNumber? I am looking for counting the frequency of Y.YNumber based on X.XNumber. But I do see a lot in here I can learn from, so thank you! @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: No, it does what you asked - `which XNumbers had the most YNumbers`. It's counting the *count* of rows in the group. There's no frequency in SQL, that's a statistical term. There are no variables in these queries either.  `GROUP BY` breaks the results into groups defined by the group fields and calculates an aggregate function in that group. Your original query resulted in groups of a single row each. If you want to get counts per X and counts per Y you either need separate queries or a `GROUPING SETS` clause. You didn't ask for that though

Answer (score 1):

**You can simplify this quite a bit.** You don't need to join `Y`  and you don't need to use `ROW_NUMBER`. You can use `TOP (1)` and `ORDER BY` instead.

Just `GROUP BY XNumber` then `COUNT(*)`, and take the highest count.

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)
  X.XNumber,
  COUNT(*) AS YFreq
FROM XY
JOIN X ON X.XID = XY.XID
GROUP BY X.XNumber
ORDER BY
  YFreq DESC;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=43a75f42e98d740a2566ec350aea1d93)